# WP_Query how do I query two custom post types based on one post type custom field?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two custom post types, Clinics and Clinic Promos. I am having one issue as to how to add a second query. Once I query clinics by list of zipcodes, I want to filter those down by running a new query or possibly joining the queries by querying the Post ID of the clinic that is saved under the clinic promos, which is how I relate the two.

```
/*More PHP before this line determines list of zip codes*/
$zipcodelist =  implode(', ', $variabele); 

 mysqli_close($dbc); 

$args = array(   
'orderby'          => 'post_title',
'order'            => 'DESC', 
'post_type' => 'clinics',
   'meta_query' => array (
        array (
          'key' => 'cliniczipcode',
          'value' => $zipcodelist,
          'compare' => 'IN'
        )
      ) );

 // the query
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

So now that I have the list of clinics, now I need to take their ID's of the clinics and do a query for Clinic Promos post type and filter them down to only the clinic promos with those ID's.

Does anyone have any direction I can take? Any advice on how I could loop these or join them?

Comment: you might wanna check the Wordpress theme handbook  and this page in it with the link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/ and in that the section that says Creating secondary queries and loops #

Comment: Thank you! Do you think I should do maybe a get_posts first, then run like  a WP_Query inside that loop to display the Clinic Promos by ID of the clinic posts? Would that work?